# Is it NOT OK to not assign the output of function?

Tags: function, recursion, variable-assignment

The context in this example is Python 3

I see a lot of code that runs a function() and assign it to some var, but doesn't use this variable later.

```
def func():
  # do some stuff
  return value

var = func(x)
# then never use var
```

Does it matter whether I assign `var` or not because the func already returned it?
Does this behave the same if `func` is a recursive function and returns at a deeper level of recursion?

[edit]: Consider `func` is a recursive function (I'll recursively call it until i find what I need from return)

**Note:** Yes, the code could work regardless of assignment to `var` (as pointed out in comments e.g. `print()` doesn't need to be assigned), and regardless of language given specific safeguards, but the question is more about best practices, pitfalls, gotchas, etc.

THANK YOU, community!

Comment: Many (most?) programming languages allow you to get away with calling a function and discarding the return value. You could even simplify it to just `func(x)`, and not storing it even temporarily. I'm pretty sure there are programming languages that force you to do something with the result, out of some opinion on code safety. It's probably hard to write a good, single, answer to this question since it is so open-ended.

Comment: I would suggest you rewrite your question to be solely about Python 3. Otherwise it risk being closed as too open ended.

Comment: `print()` also does not assign a return value, see `print(print("X"))`.   Writing `print("X")` is found common, so why would (or should?) i write `var = print("X")` ?